# Intersection of CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2 and CGAL::Ray_2

Tags: computational-geometry, intersection, cgal

There is a function `Object intersection(Type1<Kernel> obj1, Type2<Kernel> obj2)` in CGAL which will return an object, representing intersection of two given objects of different possible types. It is [said](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Kernel_23_ref/Function_intersection.html), that intersection of `CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2` (rectangle with sides parallel to the x and y axis) and `CGAL::Ray_2` (oriented ray outgoing from given point) is either `CGAL::Point_2` or `CGAL::Segment_2` (just point or segment).

And what about the case when ray intersects rectangle in two points? Cannot see anything about it in the manual.

[image]

Comment: How can a ray intersect a rectangle in two points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by Sebastien Loriot in cgal-discuss mailing list:

> The iso_rectangle is considered as full so that what you call
>   the two point case is the segment one.